# Offline Report genearation Service with Archive in .Net

Tags: c#, report, archive

I am trying to build a web application with large amount of transactions per day with the SQL server in the back end. So I want to generate the reports every day as a offline task and keep  it ready in the server for a period of 7 days and then Archive these reports which are more than 7 days old. So I am looking at possible way to achieve this in C#.Net application. Is there  a way i can generate these reports offline in some kind of service running in scheduler and display these reports on the web application when the user requests for the report.

I know that there are reporting services like crystal reports, SSRS. but i am not sure whether i will able to achieve my requirements with these.

Any insight would be of great help

Thnaks in advance

Nayan K

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what sort of reporting you are after, this might be more of an SQL question.  We do daily roll-ups of certain data to a table using stored procedures, storing the reporting information in tables.  We also have vendor-supplied reporting for some of our stuff that generates and emails reports, as well as some of our transactional data loaded into a data warehouse with various reporting options, a couple of C# programs running from Task Scheduler on one of our servers... the list goes on.

Which model is best for you will depend on various factors, including what you personally prefer.

So the short answer is, yes, you *can* write a C# console application and run it from the Task Scheduler if that's what works for you.

Comment: Corey,Thanks for the quick reply. This solution works for me. I am looking if there are any on the shelf solutions available for handling this scenario.